# changing default browser value for attribute "required"

Tags: html, browser, default

Is it possible to change default value of the attribute `required` that we add to an  element in HTML?

For example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" placeholder="enter your email address" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Notify Me" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the code that shows the error message you refer to? its not included in the above!

Answer (score -1):

I do believe that the HTML code block you have given ought be as below:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" placeholder="enter your email address" required="required" />
  <input type="submit" value="Notify Me" />
</form>
```

And if you wanted to remove it completely:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" placeholder="enter your email address" />
  <input type="submit" value="Notify Me" />
</form>
```

Obviously as you have no URL address in the ACTION attribute of the form, the form will POST back to itself (ie. meaning the page it is hosted on, so if it was on your contact.aspx form it will post back to contact.aspx)

Comment: This is just an example.. and of course it won't do anything... this is not what I asked. One more note.. `required` attribute is expecting bool value..

Comment: When you add "Required" to the HTML form element it simply specifies the form data is required. To remove the requirement, simply remove the attribute. So to initialise it with a different value does not make any sense. And yes its Boolean in HTML5 and as above like in my sample for XHTML5

Comment: What I want to have is to change default value..for example..now when you don't write anything inside you see message "this field is required" I want to write it in another language for example..that's why I want to change the value

Comment: In HTML5 you can add the LANG attribute to an element, So whichever element it is that is showing the message your talking about (Which is not included in your post above!) you ought to be able to add something along the lines of lang="fr"  for French or lang="de" for German you ought to find further information here: http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/

Comment: This page at W3.org gives you step by step instructions on how to implement language attributes in XML and HTML. I hope it helps point you in the correct direction. Link: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags